# How to Sort Descending with ActionBar in Live Data Recycleriview?

Tags: android, kotlin

**Iam using observe for recyclerview Adapter.There is Default Name Sort Ascending.I need to use Sort Descending after click actionbar**

```
private fun getAllTeams(){
    viewModel.getMyGroupMembers().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        val sortedDescending = descending(it) // -> it have to be in onOptionsItemSelected
        val sortedList = it.sortedBy {
            it.name }

        Log.d("sorted",sortedList.toString())
        scoreAdapter.submitList(sortedList)
        scoreAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    })
}
```

**After click a navigation item it will be change with Sort Descending Salary(DataClass variable)**

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == R.id.menuTogle){
        //descending() // -> How can i use the method here?
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

**Its my descending method**

```
private fun descending (getList: List<DataClass>) : List<DataClass>{

    val test = getList.sortedByDescending {
      it.value
    }
    return test
}
```

**How do I combine all this in the observer?**

```
class TeamScoreTableFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentTeamScoreTableBinding
private lateinit var scoreAdapterBinding: ItemScoreLayoutBinding
private val scoreAdapter: ScoreAdapter by inject()
private val viewModel : ScoreViewModel by inject()



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = FragmentTeamScoreTableBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
    scoreAdapterBinding = ItemScoreLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)

    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    getAllTeams()
    getGroups()

    binding.rvScoreRecyclerView.apply {

        adapter = this@TeamScoreTableFragment.scoreAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    }
}

private fun getAllTeams(){
    viewModel.getMyGroupMembers().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        val sortedDescending = descending(it)
        val sortedList = it.sortedBy {
            it.name }

        Log.d("sorted",sortedList.toString())
        scoreAdapter.submitList(sortedDescending)
        scoreAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    })
}

private fun getGroups() {
    val test = viewModel.getAllGroups()
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_togle_items,menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == R.id.menuTogle){

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

private fun descending (getList: List<DataClass>) : List<DataClass>{

    val test = getList.sortedByDescending {
      it.value
    }
    return test
}
```

Comment: Create a global variable (say xyz) of your "it" object. When you get your response do xyz = it
Then use xyz in onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: can you with code explain please.Iam a beginner:)

Comment: Okay, can you post the start of this class/activity where you call this onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: i posted all fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentTeamScoreTableBinding
private lateinit var scoreAdapterBinding: ItemScoreLayoutBinding
private val scoreAdapter: ScoreAdapter by inject()
private val viewModel : ScoreViewModel by inject()

private lateinit var items : List<DataClass>



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = FragmentTeamScoreTableBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
    scoreAdapterBinding = ItemScoreLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)

    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    getAllTeams()
    getGroups()

    binding.rvScoreRecyclerView.apply {

        adapter = this@TeamScoreTableFragment.scoreAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    }
}

private fun getAllTeams(){
    viewModel.getMyGroupMembers().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        items = it

        val sortedList = it.sortedBy {
            it.name }

        Log.d("sorted",sortedList.toString())
        scoreAdapter.submitList(sortedList)
        scoreAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    })
}

private fun getGroups() {
    val test = viewModel.getAllGroups()
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_togle_items,menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == R.id.menuTogle){
        descending(items)
        scoreAdapter.submitList(items)
        scoreAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

private fun descending (getList: List<DataClass>) : List<DataClass>{

    val test = getList.sortedByDescending {
      it.value
    }
    return test
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Do you mean so?**
private var items : List<DataClass>? = null

private fun getAllTeams(){
    viewModel.getMyGroupMembers().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        items = it
        
        val sortedList = it.sortedBy {
            it.name }

        Log.d("sorted",sortedList.toString())
        scoreAdapter.submitList(sortedList)
        scoreAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    })
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == R.id.menuTogle){
        items?.let { descending(it) }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Comment: No, simply do **if (item.itemId == R.id.menuTogle){
        descending(items) 
    }** in onOptionsItemSelected